# Works perfect but cell does't update

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the formula I'm using in Excel sheet.It works fine but doesn't update sometimes and sometimes does what can be the reason

```
=IF(F3=1,SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6))),IF(F3=2,SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6+1))),SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6+2)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get away from all the volatile functions with INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(F:G,ROW()-12,IF(F3=1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula:

```
=IF(F3=1, 
   SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6))), 
   IF(F3=2, 
     SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6+1))), 
     SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6+2)))
     )
   )
```

can be written simpler as:

```
SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-12,6 + IF(F3<=2,F3-1,2)))))
```

But this does not solve the problem....